# not understanding how to dynamically add functionality to a Ruby class via modules

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to do this simplest of Ruby metaprogramming things and can't get it to work. I'd like to have a module called Logger that if the class extending / including ... it can call x_mod that will then allow functionality such as the method log to be available on instances of that class. This is purely for learning and not at all meant for code in a project. This is

```
module Logger
  def x_mod
    def self.log
      puts "I want to log here #{inspect}"
    end
  end

  #def say_hello
  #  puts "saying hello"
  #end
end

class Jt
  #include Logger
  #include MyModule
  extend Logger
  x_mod
end
```

and get the following:

```
1.9.3-p392 :004 > require './jt'
 => false 
1.9.3-p392 :005 > j=Jt.new
 => #<Jt:0x007fecf48fafa0> 
1.9.3-p392 :006 > j.log
NoMethodError: undefined method `log' for #<Jt:0x007fecf48fafa0>
    from (irb):6
    from /Users/jt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p392 :007 >
```

Any ideas on getting to next step? thx

Comment: `require` is returning false. Try exiting IRB, rentering, and using `load` instead of `require`. Whats the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module Logger
  def x_mod
    define_method(:log) do
      puts "I want to log here #{inspect}"
    end
  end
end

class Jt
  extend Logger
  x_mod # comment me out to make log fail later
end

j = Jt.new
j.log
```

Comment: thx matt, would you say that this is a reasonable way to show ruby macro-based metaprogramming (ie using define_method)? Would define_method(:log) just translate into `def log`?

Comment: With *your* code, `Jt.log` will work; a class method is brought into existence in Jt. But you asked for `j.log` to work: you want an instance method to be brought into existence in Jt.

Comment: ok cool - just trying to figure this out. baby steps, appreciate help. Going to reread chapter on Metaprogramming in Pickaxe :-)

Comment: Personally I *never* nest `def`; I don't even like the fact that it's legal. `define_method` (and friends) has big advantages: the block is a closure, the eval context is clear (and flexible), the intention is evident, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Whoops, sorry about previous answer, didn't see Logger as a module. Check this out: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/ you want to use include instead of extend.

This code works just fine:

```
module Logger
  def x_mod
    def self.log
      puts "I want to log here #{inspect}"
    end
  end

  #def say_hello
  #  puts "saying hello"
  #end
end

class Jt
  include Logger
end

jtlog = Jt.new
Jt.log
```

Comment: An instance method is desired, not a class method.